# SQL code simplifying with ISNULL or COALESCE assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

so i have this stored procedure and i was asked to simplify it by using a ISNULL or COALESCE but i can't seem to make it work

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetCount]

    @Session NVARCHAR(7),
    @Activity BIT = true

AS

IF @Activity = 1 
BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT([user].[ActivityID]) AS [Count]
    FROM [ActivityListing] AS [act]
        INNER JOIN [ActivityListingDescriptions] AS [actDesc] 
            ON [act].[ActivityID] = [actDesc].[ActivityID]
    WHERE [act].[ListingSession] = @Session 
        AND [act].[ListingStatus] IN ('P','Q','N')
END
ELSE 
    SELECT COUNT([user].[ActivityID]) AS [Count]
    FROM [ActivityListing] AS [act]
        INNER JOIN [ActivityListingDescriptions] AS [actDesc] 
            ON [act].[ActivityID] = [actDesc].[ActivityID]
    WHERE [act].[ListingSession] = @Session 
        AND [act].[ListingStatus] NOT IN ('')
```

The problem i am encountering here is that it's not a value i am passing in, instead i am changing the query itself , One is `WHERE ... IN` and the other is `WHERE ... NOT IN` and so it wont allow me to write a query as a returned result.  Is there another way to accomplish this task of simplifying the code?

Comment: I would leave it alone.  I've seen epic FAILS (like bringing a system to its knees) from people trying to "simplify" already fast running SQL code.  When it comes to SQL code, I only change code that has a bug or runs too slow.  If it runs fast, leave it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` you can combine `WHERE` conditions to single query:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GetCount]
    @Session NVARCHAR(7),
    @Activity BIT = true
AS
    SELECT COUNT([user].[ActivityID]) AS [Count]
    FROM [ActivityListing] AS [act]
        INNER JOIN [ActivityListingDescriptions] AS [actDesc] 
            ON [act].[ActivityID] = [actDesc].[ActivityID]
    WHERE [act].[ListingSession] = @Session 
        AND ((@Activity = 1 AND [act].[ListingStatus] IN ('P','Q','N') ) 
            OR (@Activity <> 1 AND [act].[ListingStatus] NOT IN ('')))
```

If value of `@Activity` is 1 then the `IN` part of the condition will be executed, if it is anything else but 1, then the `NOT IN` condition will be executed

Comment: it is hard to tell with out more info (schema, indexes, execution plans, etc) but in general, adding an `OR` in a `WHERE` isn't usually good for being able to use an index (think table scan).  If you don't get index usage, you could try `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` which will eliminate the portion of the `OR` based on the runtime value of @Activity.  This will cost you a recompile each time.  In that case I'd leave them as two separate queries.